# python class method __del__ with xlsxwriter.workbook.close()

Tags: python, xlsxwriter, del

```
class house_crawl():
def __init__(self):
    self.row=0
    self.workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(self.getdesktoppath() + '\\house_price.xlsx')
    self.worksheet1 = self.workbook.add_worksheet()
    self.worksheet1.write_row(self.row,0,['address','describe1','describle2','price','avg_price'])
    self.row+=1
def __call__(self, url):
    self.page_crawl(url)
def __del__(self):
    self.workbook.close()
def page_crawl(self,url):
    page=requests.get(url)
    tree=html.fromstring(page.text)
    for house in tree.xpath('//*[@class="house-item clearfix"]'):
        address=house.xpath('div[1]/p[3]/text()')[0]
        address=re.sub('\r|\n| ','',address)
        #print(address)浦东-潍坊崂山路571弄（旧址崂山东路571弄）
        d1=[]
        for i in house.xpath('div[1]/p[1]/child::*'):
            d1.append(i.xpath('text()')[0])
        st=','
        d1=st.join(d1)
        # print(d1)东欣高层,3室1厅,70平
        d2=house.xpath('div[1]/p[2]/text()')
        stringt=','
        d2=stringt.join(d2)
        d2 = re.sub('\r|\n| ','',d2)
        #print(d2)南,中层,中装,1991年
        price=house.xpath('div[2]/p[1]/text()')[0]
        #print(price)580万
        avg_price=house.xpath('div[2]/p[2]/text()')[0]
        if '元/平' not in avg_price:
            avg_price = house.xpath('div[2]/p[3]/text()')[0]
        #print(avg_price)83400元/平
        self.worksheet1.write_row(self.row, 0, [address,d1,d2,price,avg_price])
        self.row+=1
def getdesktoppath(self):
    return os.path.join(os.path.expanduser("~"), 'Desktop')
```

he exception thrown is:

```
Exception ignored in: <bound method house_crawl.__del__ of <__main__.house_crawl object at 0x000001A14533B940>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/pythoncode/crawl/house.py", line 15, in __del__
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xlsxwriter\workbook.py", line 311, in close
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xlsxwriter\workbook.py", line 619, in _store_workbook
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xlsxwriter\packager.py", line 131, in _create_package
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xlsxwriter\packager.py", line 188, in _write_worksheet_files
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xlsxwriter\xmlwriter.py", line 41, in _set_xml_writer
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\codecs.py", line 895, in open
AttributeError: module 'builtins' has no attribute 'open'
```

It says the 'self.workbook.close()' in **del** is wrong.
I don't understand.......
please help me !

Comment: please fix your indentations so ppl can help you

Comment: Why did you give us only the first few characters of the traceback, cutting it off right before the useful part, just to instead paraphrase it as "it says the 'self.workbook.close()' in del is wrong", which is useless?

Comment: Also, why have you created a `__del__` method in the first place> Does `xlsxwriter.Workbook` not `close` itself when deleted?

Comment: @abarnert  my apologize

Comment: That error is bizarre. Why is anyone calling `codecs.open` in Python 3? And how is `builtins.open` not there? This looks like someone running Python 3 against a Python 2 stdlib… except that I doubt you'd get anywhere near this trying that.

Comment: OK, I now see why `codecs.open`—this code actually runs on not just 2.6+/3.2+, but even 2.5 and 3.1. But I still don't see how `builtins.open` could be missing.

Comment: Don't rely on `__del__` for cleanup. This sounds like the kind of thing that happens if an object finally gets GC'ed so late in interpreter shutdown that even the builtins are gone.

Comment: @user2357112 can you tell me another solution???

Comment: An explicit `close` method and `__enter__` and `__exit__` for context manager support, just like any other object that needs closing, like the workbook you're trying to call `close` on.

Comment: @ user2357112 reasonable

Answer (score 0):

```
2022-07-06 20:02:33 
2022-07-06 20:02:33 Traceback (most recent call last):
2022-07-06 20:02:33   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/encodings/__init__.py", line 31, in <module>
2022-07-06 20:02:33   File "/var/www/codecs.py", line 14, in <module>
2022-07-06 20:02:33 AttributeError
2022-07-06 20:02:33 : 
2022-07-06 20:02:33 module 'builtins' has no attribute 'open'
2022-07-06 20:02:33
```